# String to Date Conversion in iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have refer previous examples from here. But still problem in null value.

String Value is :==> strDate = "09-05-2012 00:00:00"

I want output as :==> May 09, 2012

My Code:

```
NSString *strDateFormat;//[strDate substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
strDateFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", strDate];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSDate *disDate = [df dateFromString:strDateFormat];
[df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];

strDateFormat = [df stringFromDate:disDate];

lblDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", strDateFormat];

[df release];
```

It gives (null) value. Because disDate has (null) value.

Why disDate set to nil..?
Any solution..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gotta tell the formatter what format to expect when reading a string, too.

```
NSString *string = @"09-05-2012 00:00:00";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:string];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
NSString *formattedString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-(NSString*)getStringWithFormat:(NSString*)pStrDate fromFormat:(NSString*)pFromFormat toFormat:(NSString*)pToFormat
{
    NSDateFormatter *dtFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dtFormatter setDateFormat:pFromFormat];
    NSDate *fromFormatDate = [dtFormatter dateFromString:pStrDate];
    [dtFormatter setDateFormat:pToFormat];
    return [dtFormatter stringFromDate:fromFormatDate];
}
```

and call it like this

```
NSString *strDate = [self getStringWithFormat:@"09-05-2012 00:00:00" fromFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:MM:SS" toFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
```

This is common function, You can use it for any formats, Just you have to pass that format in argument.

Comment: Hey I have used. But Still its returning null value.
NSDate *fromFormatDate -> consumes <nil> value.

Now any idea.?

Comment: Plz pass the fromFormat same as your string Ex. If your String is 05/12/2011 then fromFormat should be MM/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

you have not set the formater pattern

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
    NSDate *convertedDate = [df dateFromString:origDate];
    [df release];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *strDateFormat; //[strDate substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];

strDateFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", strDate];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
 // ###### Set dateformat also here according to strDateFormat 

NSDate *disDate = [df dateFromString:strDateFormat];

[df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];

strDateFormat = [df stringFromDate:disDate];

lblDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", strDateFormat];

[df release];
```